# how to change the format of date in django validation error

Tags: django

I defined the following model:

```
class Registration(models.Model):

    date_of_birth=models.DateField(blank=True, default='', null=True)

    class Meta:  
        db_table = "gym_registration"
```

Now I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."].
```

please solve this error.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]. please solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

A `default=''` does not make sense. A `DateField` stores a date, not a string. Yes, you can write a string to that field, since Django will then convert this to a date, but an empty string is not a valid formatted string, unless of course you define a "weird" format that for example would map the empty string on a certain date, but that would be bad software design. If you make it NULLable, you can store `None` in it as well, but not a generic string.

You probably want to alter this to:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)
```

You probably need to remove the corresponding migration file as well, and generate a new migration file.